# Tortoise not recognizing certain .cs file

Tags: tortoisesvn

I created a new class in VS.  For some reason Tortoise is not picking it up and I can't figure out why.  Wondering if anyone has had this issue?

I am not excluding .cs or do not have * in my filter so not sure what the deal is.  All other files picked up just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate to state the obvious first, but did you add it to the repository first before trying to commit it?

Comment: Yes, but I should not have to manually right-click and add.  Tortoise always picks it up in the commit dialog..meaning it shows you uncommitted files and you have the option right there to select those uncommitted files to include in your current commit.  For some reason this .cs file was not showing in the dialog and that's what was troubling.  Yes, I ended up having to go the old route, and manually force it by right-clicking the file itself and adding it.